# No python interpreter found. Abort - Opscenter

Tags: python, path, opscenter

Just want to ask on what possibilities to check on our opscenter rpm. we are getting this error when starting the opscenter

```
[opscenter@mybox]$ sudo /etc/init.d/opscenterd start
Starting Cassandra cluster manager opscenterd
Starting opscenterdNo python interpreter found. Abort.
[opscenter@mybox start-stop-scripts]$ cd            [FAILED]
```

I see python is installed, but not sure how to make the opscenter point it on this location

```
[opscenter@mybox ~]$ python -V ; which python
Python 2.7.1
/opt/mybox/pkg/python/bin/python
```

Opscenter is installed on /opt/mybox/pkg/opscenter and there are some variables I'm seeing on the opscenter file located in bin

```
# get around sudo vagaries in setting $HOME
if [ "x$OPSC_HOME" = "x" ]; then
if [ $is_mac = 1 ]; then
    OPSC_HOME="/Users/$USER"
else
    OPSC_HOME=$(getent passwd $(id -u) | cut -d ':' -f 6)
fi
fi
export HOME=$OPSC_HOME

cd "$(dirname "$0")"/../

if [ $(uname -m) = "x86_64" ]; then
PY_ARCH="amd64"
else
PY_ARCH="i386"
fi

# we support python2.6-2.7
PYVERSIONS="2.6 2.7"

[ -z "$PYTHON" ] && \
for i in $PYVERSIONS; do
which python$i > /dev/null 2>&1 && PYTHON=$(which python$i)
done
[ -n "$PYTHON" ] || {
echo "No python interpreter found. Abort." >&2
exit 3
}

PY_VER=$($PYTHON -c "import platform; v = platform.python_version(); print     v[:v.index('.', 2)]")
 if [ $is_mac = 1 ]; then
 PY_DISTRO="./lib/py-osx/${PY_VER}/amd64" # always use 64bit for OS X
 elif [ -f "/etc/system-release" ]; then
 # This branch is for the Amazon Linux distribution
 # We will use the highest level "VER" available because Amazon Linux
 # does not use version numbers like RHEL and Centos
 VER=`ls -1 ./lib/py-redhat/${PY_VER}/ | sort -n | tail -n 1`
 PY_DISTRO="./lib/py-redhat/${PY_VER}/shared/${PY_ARCH}:./lib/py-redhat/${PY_VER}/${VER}/${PY_ARCH}"
elif [ -f "/etc/redhat-release" ]; then
VER=`rpm -q centos-release --qf %{VERSION}`
if [ 1 -eq $? ]; then
    VER=`rpm -q redhat-release --qf %{VERSION}` # RHEL 5
    if [ 1 -eq $? ]; then
        VER=`rpm -q redhat-release-server --qf %{VERSION}` # RHEL 6
        if [ 1 -eq $? ]; then
            VER=`rpm -q enterprise-release --qf %{VERSION}` # Oracle Linux
        fi
    fi
fi
VER=`echo $VER | cut -b 1`
PY_DISTRO="./lib/py-redhat/${PY_VER}/shared/${PY_ARCH}:./lib/py-redhat/${PY_VER}/${VER}/${PY_ARCH}"
else
 PY_DISTRO="./lib/py-debian/${PY_VER}/${PY_ARCH}"
 fi

export PYTHONPATH="./src:\
/usr/lib/python${PY_VER}/site-packages:\
./src/lib/python${PY_VER}/site-packages:\
./lib/python${PY_VER}/site-packages:\
./lib/py:\
${PY_DISTRO}:\
${PYTHONPATH}:"
```

Comment: What does `which python2.7` print when you run it in the Terminal?

Comment: [opscenter@mybox ~]$ which python 2.7
/opt/mybox/pkg/python/bin/python
/usr/bin/which: no 2.7 in (/usr/kerberos/bin:/opt/mybox/pkg/python/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/mybox/pkg/opscenter/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin)

Comment: You put a space between `python` and `2.7`, so `which` thinks they are two separate commands. Please try it again, without the intervening space, and paste the results into your question, in a code block so that the formatting is preserved.

Comment: [opscenter@mybox ~]$ which python2.7

/opt/mybox/pkg/python/bin/python2.7

Comment: can you echo the $i in the for i in $PYVERSIONS ? I'm a bit rusty in shell, but it would be better to `for i in 2.6 2.7; do`, quotes can make it not split the string.

Comment: Sorry. I should have mentioned that you need to run that command as root, using `sudo`, since that's how you're launching `opscenterd`. My guess is that python2.7 is not on the PATH of the root user.

Comment: [opscenter@mybox ~]$ for i in "2.6 2.7"; do which python$i ; done
/usr/bin/which: no python2.6 in (/usr/kerberos/bin:/opt/mybox/pkg/python/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/mybox/pkg/opscenter/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin)
/usr/bin/which: no 2.7 in (/usr/kerberos/bin:/opt/mybox/pkg/python/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/mybox/pkg/opscenter/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin)

Comment: I already got rid of the error by adding this on the opscenter from bin file

   `# we support python2.6-2.7
    PYVERSIONS="2.6 2.7"

[ -z "$PYTHON" ] && \
for i in $PYVERSIONS; do
    which python$i > /dev/null 2>&1 && PYTHON=$(which python$i)
done
if [ -z "$PYTHON" ]; then
  [ -d "/opt/mybox/pkg/python" ] && PYTHON=/opt/mybox/pkg/python/bin/python2.7
fi
[ -n "$PYTHON" ] || {
    echo "No python interpreter found. Abort." >&2
    exit 3
}

Comment: You can bypass that attempt to find python 2.6 or 2.7 by setting `PYTHON` in your environment to the path of the python interpreter you want to use. That is: `PYTHON=/opt/mybox/pkg/python/bin/python /path/to/bin/opscenter`

Answer (score 1):

> not sure how to make the opscenter point it on this location

Since this is your specific question, I'll echo my comment here as an answer.

You can set `PYTHON` to your python interpreter prior to running the opscenter init script. This will bypass the check for python 2.6 or 2.7 (via the `-z` test) and allow you to just tell the script where python is.

```
$ export PYTHON=/opt/mybox/pkg/python/bin/python
$ sudo /etc/init.d/opscenterd start
```

As for the root reason why this is happening, I suspect that PM 2Ring is correct and python is not on the path of the user (root, it seems) that's starting OpsCenter.